# Blank Calendar In IE9

Tags: calendar, internet-explorer-9

I'm using IE Calendar.

```
<ie:calendar ID="Cal1" STYLE="behavior:url (calendar.htc); width: 200; height: 150;">    </ie:calendar>
```

...

It works fine in IE7, IE8 but shows blank widget in IE9.

IE9 Version: 9.0.8112 16421.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: I'm using exactly the same version of IE and it works for me on this page: http://samples.msdn.microsoft.com/workshop/samples/author/behaviors/library/calendar/calendar.htm

Answer (score 1):

I came across an article on Microsoft Support site.

This behavior can occur if the file association for Hypertext Markup Language (HTML) component (.htc) files is not in the registry.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313853